# React bundle doesnt work when I put it inside an Html script tag and open the html through a browser

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack

Normally in production and development using webpack this works fine. But when I attach the react code to just a regular HTML it doesn't mount itself. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,width=device-width" />
    <title>Sit</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="modal-hook"></div>
    <div id="backdrop-hook"></div>
    <div id="root">444</div>
    <script>
     // Copy pasted React bundle here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you loading your app after directly pasting `react` scripts in html file. Loading from a server or opening as a html page in browser with `file://` protocol?

Comment: opening it through html page in browser file file://

Answer (score 0):

A simple `React`  app would load from html page. Check this [example](https://github.com/ccPrathap/react-training/blob/master/test-react-play.html).

Whereas a full fledged app not only need just `react` bundle files. You should add all it's necessary dependencies like `chunk`/`css`/`vendor` files with all the required `polyfills`. And the `main` bundle file might be having relative file references with in that.

> After all it's a set of JS files after bundling the code. If you add all it's necessary dependencies in the correct format, it will load without any issues.